# Memory profiling of Xamarin Android apps in Android Studio Profiler on Android 7.1

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, memory-profiling

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/profiling) gives instructions on how to profile memory of a Xamarin Android app in the Android Studio profiler. [The memory profiler documentation for the profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler#advanced-profiling) says that devices running Android 7.1 or older must check the setting for "Enable additional support for older devices (API level < 26)" in the Run Configuration settings in order to enable much of the detailed profile information. However, I believe that this setting only applies to apps built with Android Studio, i.e. not Xamarin apps. Regarding this setting, the profiler docs say: "To show you additional profiling data when running a device with Android 7.1 or lower, Android Studio must inject monitoring logic into your compiled app". **Is there any way to "inject" this monitoring logic into an apk built with Xamarin?**

Comment: There is no more details in Android developers. It needs to get the support from Android Studio.